# Spring boot Maven based App integration to spring mvc gradle based app

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc, gradle, backend

I have query to all,
I have a 2 applications, these are on-prem applications working independent to each other,
I have create a spring boot application which act as a middle layer, with this layer I can perform CRU{Create, read, update, search} in one of the application.
EG: Image attached for ref:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsZc9.png)

Now i want to include this middle layer to Application 1,

Although, its a working solution, just i want to remove the middle layer.

Is there a best practice to do so...

I have create a middle layer,
Now, I want to reduce the extra steps to re-configure a new service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven or gradle is for packaging your dependent JAR files. If you use either one that is fine.

For removing middle layer. My approach will be remove second layer code and add it to first layer.

1. find maven dependancy and convert it to equivalent gradle dependancy.
2. copy and paste code from second layer to first layer with all unit test cases. to make sure that functionality will not change.

Second Approach.
change middle layer to submodule of first gradle project. but still you need to change maven dependancy to gradle dependancy.